# Gmail lets me use my old password

Tags: passwords, email, password-management, gmail

My university's email works through Gmail and I can log on to it either through my uni's website or in Gmail. I recently changed my password and I use it to log in to the schools secure WiFi, school site, blackboard, and to access my email through the school's website etc.
However, when I try to log in to my email through Gmail it uses my old password. Also when I change my password it logs me out of everything including my email through the website but, I stay logged into the Gmail app on my phone. How is this possible?

Also I have notified my uni's IT department.

**Edit 1:**

https://apps.astate.edu/SAML/gmail.php

This is how I can acces my email through my school's site. To access it through Gmail I just go to [mail.google.com](http://mail.google.com). 
When I use the first link I type in my new password. When I use the second link I have to type in my old password. I didn't need to do anything special to get my email to work with Gmail it just works. Until recently that is.

**Edit 2:**

When I try to change my email in google this is what I see.[image]

Also note that is says that the last time I change my password was August 28 even though I changed it a couple of weeks ago.

Then when I click the "password & sign-in method" it takes me here.
[image]

I click submit and it sends me here.[image]

This is the same page I use to change my password as if I had done it through the school's website.

Comment: Are you talking about [managing your school's email *through* gmail?](http://notebooks.com/2009/08/27/how-to-use-gmail-to-manage-your-school-email-2/)

Comment: What happens if you go to Gmail and change your Google password there? Can you still login to Gmail through your school's website? If not, it likely means that your school is storing a copy of your Google password and using it to login to Google (likely for an IMAP connection) for you. Very bad. Shame on them.

Comment: When I try to change my password in Gmail it sends me to the school's account manager which is how we always have to change our passwords.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a poorly done configuration on the school's part. I also have a Gmail account managed by the school that is tied to the school's SSO. The only thing you can do is talk to your school's IT department, and hopefully they will fix their mistake.

In the mean time, enabling 2-factor sign-on will protect your account from compromise until you can get your passwords sorted out.

Comment: Short and meaningful :)